# Python - ROS - Windows

Tags: python, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Breaking up several questions I asked here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/45234/multiplatform-dotnet-ros-workflow-redistribution-issues/

Issue #2: Seems like WinRos Sdk is not working with python, as ROS doesn't find my package.

I failed to find a workflow on using ROS with python on windows - the tutorials point only to using cpp modules.

Is it possible to run python ROS in Windows? What should I run to get ROS to find the package (assuming it's written in python)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45261/python---ros---windows/) by [TiagoRibeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3310/tiagoribeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did it with installing python x86_64 in hydro x64 on windows 8.1 using windows sdk 7.1 (before installing it you have to uninstall redistributables 2010 and reinstall afterwards).

---

Originally posted by [Morgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/21508/morgane/) with karma: 41 on 2015-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0